# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined typescript, but still does

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema relacionado con json creo, por que a pesar de que el navegador lanza este error, si que esta usando la función y leyendo el array correctamente.

Mi definición de tipos:

```
interface alramaid {
  telefono: string
}

interface arrayAlarmResponse extends Array<alramaid>{};

getAlarms() {
    return this.http.get<arrayAlarmResponse>('http://localhost:8000/getAlarmas.php');
  }
```

Y luego en mi componente llamo al servicio de la siguiente manera, en ngOnInit para tener la información al cargar la página, ya que la necesito en ese instante:

```
this.alarmas.getAlarms().subscribe(
  (data: Array<alarmaResponse>) => {
    this.alarms = data;
  }
);
```

Intento leer la clase de la siguiente forma  y aquí es donde salta el error a pesar de que lo lee y muestra correctamente:

```
for (let a of this.alarms) {
  if (a['telefono'] == tel) {
    esta = true;
  }
```

Está función es llamada desde un html para ver si se cumple y mostrar o no un boton.

Los datos que se envian desde el servidor son del tipo [{telefono:'2334254'},{telefono:'2334254'},....]

Comment: Considera replicar y adjuntar un ejemplo en [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subnxf), ya que a simple vista falta código por analizar

Comment: Tienes razón, pero no creo que publicar todo el código sea lo suyo, voy a editar unas cosas que faltan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución muy tonta, al parecer que tu definas el tipo en una variable da igual, lo que importa es que le asignes un objeto de ese tipo, así que en ngoninit al inicio he puesto:

```
this.alarms = new Array<alarmaResponse>();
```

Esto elimina los errores, no se si es la solución correcta por que soy bastante nuevo en este lenguaje, pero a mi me ha resuelto el problema.

Comment: No es que dé igual. Lo que te debe estar pasando es que no has definido el atributo `alarms`. El servicio da los datos asíncronamente; mientras tanto, el componente falla al intentar renderizar desde `alarms`. Lo habitual es dar un valor vacío (`this.alarms: alamaResponse[] = []`) o desactivar el elemento con `ng-If` mientras devuelve datos el servicio.

Comment: Con `this.alarms = []` basta

Answer (score 0):

Acuerdate que las subscripciones a observables son asincronas. El problema es que tu funcion intenta recorrer this.alarms antes de que llegue la respuesta de la API.

Intenta hacer algo como:

```js
this.alarmas.getAlarms().subscribe((data: Array<alarmaResponse>) => {
   this.alarms = data;
   this.findIfThereIs();
});

findIfThereis() {
  for (let a of this.alarms) {
    if (a['telefono'] == tel) {
      isThere = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Asi cuando buscas el telefono en tu lista, esta lista ya no es undefined.

Comment: Se que son asíncronas estas llamadas, ese es el tema, no puedo poner esa función dentro del subscribe, necesito que este fuera.